# Why isn't meteor injecting the text from my template helpers?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor

Im trying to dynamically generate a table of two different sets of data. My database isnt empty and the returns have been verified as well. but when i check the rendered page the corresponding html isnt there as if nothing as returned.

template/html:

```
<template name="room">
<div class="container-fluid">
<h1> Sprint Retrospective</h1>
<hr>
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control thoughts" placeholder="Thoughts..." aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
<span class="input-group-addon">
        <input id="wentWell" type="checkbox" aria-label="..."> Went Well
      </span>
<span class="input-group-addon">
        <input id="wentWrong" type="checkbox" aria-label="..."> Went Wrong
      </span>
 <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Submit!</button>
      </span>
</div>
<hr>
{{#if haveCards}}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">Went Well</div>
                {{#each wentWell}}
                    {{>card}}
                {{/each}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">Went Wrong</div>
                {{#each wentWrong}}
                    {{>card}}
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/if}}
</div>
</template>
```

Javascript:

```
"use strict";
/**
*
**/
var Cards = new Mongo.Collection('cards');
var allCards;
var wentWellCards;
var wentWrongCards;
if(Meteor.isClient){
    Tracker.autorun(function(){
         allCards = Cards.find({},{sort:{createdAt:-1}});
         wentWellCards = Cards.find({category:"Went Well"},{sort:{createdAt:-1}});
         wentWrongCards = Cards.find({category:"Went Wrong"},{sort:{createdAt:-1}});
    });
    Template.room.helpers({
        haveCards: function(){
            if(allCards != null && allCards != undefined && allCards.length > 0)
                return true;
            return false;
        },
        wentWell: function(){
            return this.wentWellCards;
        },
        wentWrong: function(){
            return this.wentWrongCards;
        }   
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Jeremy answer its actually more in point, but..

Lets try to fix that code a little bit.

Lets change the `wentWell` and `wentWrong` helpers to look more clean like this.

```
    wentWell: function(){
        return Cards.find({category:"Went Well"},{sort:{createdAt:-1}});
    },
    wentWrong: function(){
        return Cards.find({category:"Went Wrong"},{sort:{createdAt:-1}});
    }
```

Also for the `haveCards` helpers you can do something like

```
haveCards: function(){
 return Cards.find().count() >= 1 //for example or return just findOne() 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your helpers should return `wentWellCards` instead of `this.wentWellCards`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your helpers are not reactive, so, when the data is loaded (which happens after the page is rendered) the helpers are not re-run.

Simply, call the reactive methods (the minimongo queries) in the helper directly. This will get them re-run once the data is available

Also, when you check the count, you need to fetch the collection

```
Cards = new Mongo.Collection('cards');
if(Meteor.isServer){
    Meteor.publish('cards', function() {
        return Cards.find({},{sort:{createdAt:-1}});
    });
}

if(Meteor.isClient){
    Template.room.onCreated(function(){
        this.subscribe('cards');
    });
    Template.room.helpers({
        haveCards: function(){
            var allCards = Cards.find({},{sort:{createdAt:-1}}).fetch();
            return (allCards != null && allCards != undefined && allCards.length > 0);
        },
        wentWell: function(){
            return wentWellCards = Cards.find({category:"Went Well"},{sort:{createdAt:-1}});
        },
        wentWrong: function(){
            return wentWrongCards = Cards.find({category:"Went Wrong"},{sort:{createdAt:-1}});
        }   
    });
}
```

And you will need to publish the collection from the server and subscribe from the template (unless you are using autopublish)